# How to find lock-wait queries on AgentGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I'm suffering from slow transaction of AgensGraph.
CPU Usage is extremely low.
I'm guessing that lock-wait situation.

How to find lock-wait queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can try lock-wait log of AgensGraph.

First, change parameters on "postgresql.conf"

```
log_lock_waits = on
deadlock_timeout = 1s
```

Second, restart AgensGraph.

```
$ ag_ctl stop
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
$ ag_ctl start
server starting
```

Finally, run queries and check log file.

[Session1 : block tran]

```
agens=# begin;
BEGIN
agens=# create (:n{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
agens=#
```

[Session2 : lock-wait transaction ]

```
agens=# create (:n{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
```

Check log from log file.

```
LOG:  process 3908 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 1586 after 1001.058 ms
DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 3906. Wait queue: 3908.
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (0,7) in relation "n_id_idx"
STATEMENT:  create (:n{id:1});
LOG:  process 3908 acquired ShareLock on transaction 1586 after 4639.630 ms
CONTEXT:  while inserting index tuple (0,7) in relation "n_id_idx"
STATEMENT:  create (:n{id:1});
```